# Shell or Perl script / How to sort group members in /etc/group?

Tags: perl, shell

What is the best way to sort the group members in the /etc/group file?

e.g.

```
tomcat::201:root,tux23,alex
ftp::66000:tom,alex,mike
```

I need following output:

```
tomcat::201:alex,root,tux23
ftp::66000:alex,mike,tom
```

Thanks in advance,
tux

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Can you provide some more details. May be there is some alternative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use perl one liner to sort usernames on every line,

```
perl -pe 's|([^:\n]+)$| join ",", sort split /,/, $1 |e' /etc/group
```

output

```
tomcat::201:alex,root,tux23
ftp::66000:alex,mike,tom
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{ split($4, a, ","); 
           n = asort(a);
           s = a[1]; 
           for(i = 2; i <= n; ++i) { s = s "," a[i] }
           print $1":"$2":"$3":"s
         }' /etc/group
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but I always get following error: "awk: illegal reference to array a"

Comment: I have used a Solaris box. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: On Solaris, you could try with `/usr/bin/xpg4/awk`. On Solaris 11, it should work with `gawk`.

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F: -lape 's#$F[3]#join ",",sort split /,/,$F[3]#e' /etc/group
```

or

```
perl -F: -lane 'print join ":",@F[0..2],join ",",sort split /,/,$F[3]' /etc/group
```

Answer (score 0):

Another perl one liner:

```
perl -ne 'if (/(.*:\d+:)(.*)/) {print $1.join(",",sort(split(/,/,$2)))."\n";}' /etc/group
```